# How to make nicely ordered string of strings?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have the following string which I derive from the dataframe using a for loop:

```
a = 'type_1, type_2, type_3, \n, fruit, apple, banana, \n, vegetable, potato, onions'
```

How can I modify the string so that when I run a, I get the following

```
type_1,  , type_2, type_3
fruit    , apple , banana
vegetable, potato, onions
```

I know I could put data into pandas dataframe, but the geopandas.explore does not like when there are dataframes in column. Please note, I am not running print(a), but just a. I want a to be in the above format.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "run" a? What do you imagine are the logical steps that need to be taken in order to solve the problem? Also: instead of trying to modify this string, why not modify the code that creates it from the dataframe, so that the extra spaces are already there? (After all, at that step in the process, you already know which strings are in what columns.)

Comment: For example, when one selects the box in jupyter notebook and presses shift+enter. Well, I was thinking about appending all of the necessary rows as strings into list. Then using the '.'.join(data). This will produce strong of string of strings. The issue arises here as I am trying to understand what separator to use so that the substrings appear on separate lines.

Comment: why not store it in the dataframe column as dict? Then you can run `pd.DataFrame(a)`

Comment: Geopandas.explore() does not like dataframes in column. How I am trying to solve this is to take every row from the sub dataframe, turn it into string, and concatenate resulting to strings to one another as specified in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running 'a' in jupyter, you can print 'a'. For Comma(,) you can replace it for a better view. (You have to print it to view that format)

```
b = a.replace(', \n,','\n')
print(b)
```

Output:

```
type_1, type_2, type_3
 fruit, apple, banana
 vegetable, potato, onions
```

You can also do this:

```
for i in a.split('\n,'):
    print(i.strip().strip(','))
```

It will split the string by '\n,' and iterate over that list of strings. The First strip removes any leading and trailing whitespace and the second will remove any leading and trailing Comma(,).

Output:

```
type_1, type_2, type_3
fruit, apple, banana
vegetable, potato, onions
```

this is also possible:

```
for i in a.split(', \n,'):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
type_1, type_2, type_3
 fruit, apple, banana
 vegetable, potato, onions
```